# Periodic HDD clicks

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

In the last few days I began to notice clicks from the PC case. I started listening to everything and it seems that the clicks are coming from the HDD. The PC is working as usual, but the clicks scare me (HDD: Toshiba 1TB 7200RPM 64MB P300 SATA III). I bought it new in 2021.

Also, the system has an SSD M.2, and after an hour the HDD goes into sleep mode (if I do not use programs from the HDD), at this time there are no clicks. What should I do?

Sound recording on Google Drive, duration 1 minute and there I recorded 3 clicks, I ask you to turn up the volume.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKcUJpGxQYrFTLmQG6Plhe-LD0QGTU-B/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Show SMART values.

Comment: Given the price of 1 TB SSDs, I suggest changing that HDD for an SSD if you can afford to (or even a 2 TB SSD). You know how it sounds better when the HDD goes into sleep mode? Imagine never having to wait for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, HDD clicks indicate one of 2 things:

1. That you can hear the drive heads moving as they seek to a new track.
2. That the drive is about to fail.

However, with Toshiba drives, I have eliminated #1 as a possibility, and have still heard clicking sounds on new drives.

My conclusion has been that there is something unique about Toshiba drives that makes them click at seemingly random intervals.  I agree that it's concerning.

When a situation mandates the use of Toshiba HDDs, I always am extra vigilant about monitoring S.M.A.R.T. values and any other signs of possible problems.  I also ensure that anyone using the drives has all data backed up.

Despite the clicking, I have never had a Toshiba HDD fail prematurely.  However, due to the clicking, they are never a first choice.